# User Rank from sorted set using dense ranking method

Tags: redis, leaderboard, sortedset, game-center-leaderboard

I am trying to build leaderboard for which I am using redis sorted set.
I need to return user rank who is invoking api
`/getMyRank?uid=55`

I need to return users rank using dense ranking method.
For those who are unaware of dense ranking here is the example
| uid | score| dense rank
| --- | -----| ----------
| 11  | 10   | 1
| 22  | 10   | 1
| 33  | 20   | 2
| 44  | 20   | 2
| 55  | 30   | 3

When I use
`ZRANK testKey 55`
command of redis I get value 5 but I need to return to user 3

any suggestions on how to accomplish user rank using dense ranking?

Few options in my mind

1. **bruteforce** - fetch all the scores from 0 till my score and apply dense ranking algorithm on it
   -- this is pretty heavy space and time complex tax when my data will be large
2. **(totalUniqueScoreCount above my score) + 1**
   **-- finalScore = 2 + 1 = 3**

but the problem with approach 2 is I need to have **total unique score count**

For calculating this I need to use redis hash with score as key and value as count and when calculating the user score I need to traverse the hash to get the unique scores whose count > 0. This operation is computational intensive plus it can give data inconsistency in case of race condition.